# How can I multiply two arrays with same length and return a new array with these values?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static double multi(double u[][]) {
    double x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (double j = 0; i < y.length; j++) {
            double z = x[i] * y[i];
            return z;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far. For an example, I want to multiply `arr1[] = {1,2,3};` with `arr2 [] = {4,5,6};` 
And return the same length with multiplied values with `arr1` and `arr2`. `[4,10,18]` Like this: `1*4`, `2*5`, and `3*6`.

And an important point: The task is to return it into a new array.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to return a new array, but you're returning just a double. Also, the parameter u is not used at all. I guess this should be a matrix multiplication operation, in this case the code is far off the tracks. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Your method (**milti()**) shows it accepts a two dimensional double type Array argument, yet you are hard-coding two single dimensional arrays within the method. Which is it? By the look of the method it looks like you need to accept a 2D double array, iterate over that array and multiply the columns of each row together. This supplied Array to the method would most likely be: `double[][] u = {{1.0, 4.0}, {2.0, 5.0}, {3.0, 6.0}};`....or is that a typo? The return type should also be: `double[]` not `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to preserve both arrays you could just do it like this.

```java
  double x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  double y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

  double [] result = multi(x, y);


  public static double[] multi(double[] x, double[] y) {
     if (x.length != y.length) {
          System.out.println("Arrays must be same size");
          return null;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] *= y[i];
      }
      return x;
  }
```

Or creating a new array.

```
public static double[] multi(double[] x, double[] y) {
     if (x.length != y.length) {
          System.out.println("Arrays must be same size");
          return null;
      }
      double[] result = new double[x.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        result[i] = x[i] * y[i];
      }
      return result;
  }
```

But in either case you need to

1. Make the return type a double[]
2. Make a utility method that accepts two arrays.
3. Check that the arrays are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare a new array `z` of same size as the other two array. Iterate over them, multiply each index value and return the array `z`;

```
public static double[] multi() {
     double x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
     double y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

     double z[] = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        z[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    }
   return z;
}
```

Comment: Try not to do other peoples homework. That's not what SO is for.

Comment: I guess I have seen some effort by OP and replied correspondingly. It's not like OP has written a single line question.

Comment: Correct...then point out the errors of his/her ways rather than doing the work for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two sequences.

```
public static double multi() {
    double x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    double y[] = { 4, 5, 6 };

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        result += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: OP want new array as a result.

Comment: No...The OP has **clearly** indicated what he's trying to accomplish and this is not it. How did you come to this conclusion that this is what the OP wants?

Comment: ah, you're right! double as a return type confused me.